# phpbrew Bash init failure

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am at the initial stages of preparing for multiphp nginx following a complete install of Ubuntu and the git page

http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/

I have duplicated steps followed here for clarity and re-installed Ubuntu and followed exactly what is below in case my error correction attempts were causing issues

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KbfqW5PqFejlCMV9yEUHgEr5FdCh5P6Ufv-HRQH3u9g/edit?usp=sharing

but fails with /usr/bin/env: php: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out our wiki and install the requirements

https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Requirement

```
apt-get build-dep php5
apt-get install -y php5 php5-dev php-pear autoconf automake curl libcurl3-openssl-dev build-essential libxslt1-dev re2c libxml2 libxml2-dev php5-cli bison libbz2-dev libreadline-dev
apt-get install -y libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg8-dev libjpeg8  libgd-dev libgd3 libxpm4 libltdl7 libltdl-dev
apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl
apt-get install -y gettext libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0
apt-get install -y libicu-dev
apt-get install -y libmhash-dev libmhash2
apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev libmcrypt4
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not post this without much effort trying to resolve first - about a day and many visited links.

Anyway the issue lay with thinking php was installed with Ubuntu +/ updates.
Note that phpbrew has php as one of its dependencies.
I guess a fresh OS install went against me on this occasion.

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```